# How to understand text language in utf8 encoded text?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, redis, language-detection

Redis is using utf8 code and for my project I need to get text language which is utf8 encoded text.

Is there any way that can give a clue about the language of the text?

EDIT: My project is on NodeJs programming language. In Redis maybe lua script has a way to handle this but in nodejs is there any package which can understand the text which is retrieved from Redis?

Comment: google translate can automatically detect most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a google search for "language detect node". This turned up https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-language-detect and https://github.com/dachev/node-cld.

Comment: Because I couldn't find the right english words to search what I want to find out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Language detection is not a Redis specific task. I don't known which language you are using but in Ruby you can use [whatlanguage](https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage) gem for detect langauge. I think other languages has similar libraries too.